# DropDown Menu isn't updating when something is selected(Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I am trying to create a DropDown menu in my Flutter project, but it's value doesn't change when I press on a value. I've tried several different codes and tutorials, but it never seems to change. Here is my code:

```
    body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 30.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: myController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Title',
                hintText: 'What will you call your grocery list?'),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Remind me every ',
                style: GoogleFonts.biryani(fontSize: 15.0),
              ),
              new DropdownButton<String>(
                value: 'Wednesday',
                items: <String>[
                  'Sunday',
                  'Monday',
                  'Tuesday',
                  'Wednesday',
                  'Thursday',
                  'Friday',
                  'Saturday'
                ].map((String value) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: new Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (_) {},
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Also, this code is inside of a class separate from the mainpage of the file, which is also a stateful widget. Basically, I'll end up with two stateful widgets, the main page, and this page, and it won't let me create two states. Here is the error it gives me:

```
The name 'createState' is already defined.
Try renaming one of the declarations.dartduplicate_definition
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

**-----------------------**

Just use two separate and different Stateful widget, one for the page and one for the selector, Check this dartpad to better understand how you can split your StatefulWidget into two separate StatefulWidgets

https://dartpad.dev/b07af2a7d088caeb312e5fc0cf6c5f10

**-----------------------**

You have HardCoded you "Wednesday" value, you should put it in a variable and set it on the on changed method, of course all of this should be done inside a StatefulWidget because you are managing the state

**Your stateful widget**

```
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestWidgetState createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}
```

**Your State**

```
class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {

  //Your String used for defining the selection**
  String _currentSelection = "Wednesday";

  //Your build method    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("DropDownSample"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 30.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Remind me every '),
                  DropdownButton<String>(
                    //Don't forget to pass your variable to the current value
                    value: _currentSelection,
                    items: <String>[
                      'Sunday',
                      'Monday',
                      'Tuesday',
                      'Wednesday',
                      'Thursday',
                      'Friday',
                      'Saturday'
                    ].map((String value) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: new Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    //On changed update the variable name and don't forgot the set state!
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentSelection = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Check also why you should use the setState when updating a variable ;) https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive

Comment: i have updated the question, is there a way for me to be able to keep this class in the file?

Comment: If you saw the comment I deleted, I fixed it. Apparently there was something wrong with the emulator, and it worked after running it on my phone. Thank you so much!

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I didn't saw that, but I'm happy that you managed to resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

You are hardcoding the value parameter inside the dropdown button so it'll never change. You need to make a variable in the beginning of a stateful widget class and inititalize like this

```
String value = "Wednesday";
```

Than you need to change its value **onChanged** function of the  DropdownButton and call setState to update the Ui with new values.
This is how your stateful widget class would look like

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String value = "Wednesday";
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 30.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new DropdownButton<String>(
                value: value,
                items: <String>[
                  'Sunday',
                  'Monday',
                  'Tuesday',
                  'Wednesday',
                  'Thursday',
                  'Friday',
                  'Saturday'
                ].map((String value) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: new Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState((){
                    this.value = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      )));
  }
}
```

Comment: This would work in most cases, but my problem is that this code isn't in the main class for the file, it's in a different class, but it isn't the only Stateful Widget. This means I would have to use the createState method twice, but I can't do that

Comment: i didnt understand what you mean by this @RiverRipple 
isnt in main class 
its in a diff class 
what do u mean by this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a variable outside of the DropdownButton and set the selected value to that.

Here is a sample

```
String _currentValue='Saturday';

 body: Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 30.0),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextField(
        controller: myController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Title',
            hintText: 'What will you call your grocery list?'),
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Remind me every ',
            style: GoogleFonts.biryani(fontSize: 15.0),
          ),
          new DropdownButton<String>(
            value: _currentValue,
            items: <String>[
              'Sunday',
              'Monday',
              'Tuesday',
              'Wednesday',
              'Thursday',
              'Friday',
              'Saturday'
            ].map((String value) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: new Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (_) {
              setState(() {
                  _selectedValue = _;
                });
            },
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: I have updated the question explaining why I can't use setState